# RxJS takeWhile but include the last value

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I have a RxJS5 pipeline looks like this

```
Rx.Observable.from([2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
  .takeWhile((v) => { v !== 4 })
```

I want to keep the subscription until I see 4, but I want to last element 4 also to be included in the result. So the example above should be

```
2, 3, 4
```

However, according to [official document](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeWhile), `takeWhile` operator is not inclusive. Which means when it encounters the element which doesn't match predicate we gave, it completes the stream immediately without the last element. As a result, the above code will actually output

```
2, 3
```

So my question is, what's the easiest way I can achieve `takeWhile` but also emit the last element with RxJS?

Comment: Somewhat facetious, but the easiest way would be `.takeWhile(v => v < 5)`

Comment: More seriously: https://github.com/martinsik/rxjs-extra/blob/master/src/operator/takeWhileInclusive.ts

Comment: worked for me https://github.com/MatthiasKunnen/rxjs-take-while-inclusive

Comment: Possibly not helpful, but relevant (it was what I ended up using after finding this post): RxJava [has a `takeUntil` method which takes a predicate](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#takeUntil-rx.functions.Func1-). The difference with `takeWhile` is that it _does_ include the last item.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Since RxJS 6.4.0 this is now possible with `takeWhile(predicate, true)`.

<strike>There's already an opened PR that adds an optional `inclusive` parameter to `takeWhile`: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/4115</strike>

There're at least two possible workarounds:

1. using `concatMap()`:

   ```
   of('red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange').pipe(
     concatMap(color => {
       if (color === 'green') {
         return of(color, null);
       }
       return of(color);
     }),
     takeWhile(color => color),
   )
   ```
2. Using `multicast()`:

   ```
   of('red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange').pipe(
     multicast(
       () => new ReplaySubject(1),
       subject => subject.pipe(
         takeWhile((c) => c !== 'green'),
         concat(subject.take(1),
       )
     ),
   )
   ```

I've been using this operator as well so I made it to my own set of additional RxJS 5 operators: https://github.com/martinsik/rxjs-extra#takewhileinclusive

This operator has been also discussed in this RxJS 5 issue: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2420

Jan 2019: Updated for RxJS 6

Answer (score 20):

UPDATE March 2019, `rsjx` version `6.4.0`: `takeWhile` finally have an optional `inclusive` parameter that allows to keep the first element that breaks the condition. So now the solution would be simply to pass **true** as the second argument of `takeWhile`:

```
import { takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

const cutOff = 4.5
const example = from([2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
.pipe(takeWhile(v => v < cutOff, true ))
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val =>
  console.log('inclusive:', val)
);
```

outputs:

```
inclusive: 2
inclusive: 3
inclusive: 4
inclusive: 5
```

Live here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-m7zjkr?embed=1&file=index.ts

Notice that 5 is the first element that breaks the condition. Notice that `endWith` is not really a solution when you have dynamical conditions like `v < cutOff` and you don't know what will be your last element.

Thanks @martin for pointing out the existence of this pull request.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `endWith(value)` which (unlike a lot of RxJS code) 
 is very nicely self documenting.

```
const example = source.pipe(
                            takeWhile(val => val != 4), 
                            endWith(4));
```

PS. Also note that `takeUntil` doesn't take a predicate, so if you were trying to use that operator to solve this problem you can't. It's a whole different method signature.

**Official docs:**
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/endWith

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pvuawt

Comment: **Watch out - not all operators are on learn-rxjs.io, so it's not currently the best place to learn**

Comment: Directly answering the asked question, where the final value is known, I like this as the most simple and straightforward. Of course as others have noted, the addition of an inclusive parameter to the operator in v6.4 is ideal.

Answer (score 3):

If your comparison is such that you know exactly what is the last element (like for `!==`), you can re-add it yourself:

```
Rx.Observable.from([2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
  .takeWhile((v) => v !== 4)
  .concat(Rx.Observable.of(4))
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: Looks like this is what `endWith` basically does https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/df0ea7c78767c07a6ed839608af5a7bb4cefbde5/src/internal/operators/endWith.ts

Comment: (I realize it may be new since a year ago)

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem, i needed the last element to be included so i chose to keep a reference to the subscription and unsubscribe *within the* `onNext` *callback* when the condition was met. Using your example code it would be:

```
const subscription = Observable.of('red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange')
  .subscribe(color => {
    // Do something with the value here
    if (color === 'green') {
      subscription.unsubscribe()
    }
  })
```

This worked for me because it also caused the observable source to stop emitting which is what i needed in my scenario.
I realize that i'm not using `takeWhile` operator but the the main goal is achieved and without any workarounds or extra code. 
I'm not a fan of forcing things to work in a way that they were not designed to. 
The disadvantages of this are:

- If there are any other observers subscribed, the source will keep emitting.
- The `onCompleted` does not get called for some reason if the last observer unsubscribes, but i checked that the source in fact stops emitting.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was unable to predict what the final value would be. I also just wanted a solution involving common, easy operators, and I wanted something I could reuse, so I couldn't rely on the values being truthy. The only thing I could think of was defining my own operator like this:

```
import { pipe, from } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, takeWhile, filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export function doWhile<T>(shouldContinue: (a: T) => boolean) {
  return pipe(
    switchMap((data: T) => from([
      { data, continue: true },
      { data, continue: shouldContinue(data), exclude: true }
    ])),
    takeWhile(message => message.continue),
    filter(message => !message.exclude),
    map(message => message.data)
  );
}
```

It's a little weird, but it works for me and I can import it and use it.