# RxJs Interval with takeUntil to publish last value

Tags: angular6, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have some code which polls until a task is complete

See below

```
this.simulationStatus =
  interval(2000).pipe(
    switchMap(
      () => from(this.simulationService.getSimulationStatus(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('jobId')))),
    takeUntil(this.stopPoll),
    tap(simulation => {
      if (simulation && simulation.complete) {
        if (this.stopCount == 1) {
          // Get once after complete
          this.stopPoll.next(true);
        }
        this.stopCount++;
      }
    })
  );
```

I have tried using takeUntil and takeWhile the problem is that that the last value is never published once the task is complete.

To get around this I have to include the tap method to with the stopPoll subject and incrementing the stopCount to get the last value.

So the above works but just feels a bit messy, I'm sure there must be a better way of achieving this?

I would have expected takeUntil to publish the last value or have an override to tell it to e.g takeUntil(observable, {publishLast: true})

BTW Update, the observable is subscribed to by an Angular 6 template 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is use a custom takeWhile-like operator like this:

```
const completeWith = <T>(predicate: (arg: T) => boolean) => (
  source: Observable<T>,
) =>
  new Observable<T>(observer =>
    source.subscribe(
      value => {
        observer.next(value);
        if (predicate(value)) {
          observer.complete();
        }
      },
      error => observer.error(error),
      () => observer.complete(),
    ),
  );
```

It doesn't seem like a good idea to see it as a variation of takeWhite because it's not just *taking* values *while* a condition holds, but also emits an extra value.

It might be that a more elegant solution would be make the simulation status observable emit two kinds of values: next notifications and completion notifications, similarly to how materialize/dematerialize operators work.

Comment: Looks good, I will probably use this. I agree with your comments regarding the name of takeWhile. However I'm using takeUntil and I think given it's name it makes sense that this has an overload option to emit the last value. Looking on StackOverflow others have certainly come across this situation and need this functionality built in.

Comment: The most elegant solution that I've found. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This has in the meantime been implemented in rxjs as `takeWhile(condition, ?inclusive)`:

```
timer(0, 10).pipe(
    takeWhile((x) => x < 3, true)
)
```

emits 0, 1, 2, 3

Answer (score 1):

You can also create subject and emit using next() if you want to complete the observable.

```
this.stopPoll: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
```

If you want to do complete the subscription. you can call this.stopPoll.next(true);

you can access the data in subscribe()

```
this.simulationStatus.subscribe(success=>{}, failure=>{}, complete=>{});
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I'm doing. and calling this.stopPoll.next(true) in the tap method, but I have 7 even 9 extra lines of code including declarations of stopCount and stopPoll just because the last value isn't published by default.

Comment: You can get the last value in the complete method. i.e third options of subscribe()

Comment: Also this is an angular template that is subscribing to the observable , probably should mention that also, but yes I can subscribe manually, it might be cleaner

Comment: Subscribing to complete => {} will work, but I lose the async binding to my template so I need to push it again onto another subject that the template binds to. So still a bit messy :/ ! Either that or lose the OnPush changeDetectionStrategy which becomes inefficient

Comment: Found this with takeWhile https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641246/rxjs-takewhile-but-include-the-last-value all solutions are hacky. I would suggest this is missing functionality in rxjs

Comment: Yes, will raise Issue to Ben Lesh RxJS Github.

Comment: Was just creating this issue https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4000, point him at that. But thanks for your time and effort!