# takeUntil does not work with BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have the following BehaviorSubject defined:

```
  private posts = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
```

and on init:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.posts
    .takeUntil(!this._postsLoaded)
    .subscribe(x => {
       this._postsLoaded = true;
        // do something
    });
}
```

But it gets the following error, although it should work:

```
Property 'takeUntil' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject<any>'
```

Comment: Which version of rxjs are you using?

Comment: "rxjs": "^6.0.0",

Comment: Then you must use pipes. See this [takeUntil](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html) example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use like a chain syntax , You have to install rxjs compat also for backward comptability.

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

But I would suggest use pipes

```
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
ngOnInit() {
  this.posts.pipe(
    takeUntil(!this._postsLoaded)
    ).subscribe(x => {
       this._postsLoaded = true;
        // do something
    };
}
```

Sample Stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-takeuntilexample?file=index.ts

Comment: this works, with one exception, thought - should only use takeUntil from rxjs, not from compact, as it throws an error

Comment: @Yuvals if you are using pipe , not need to install compat package

Answer (score 0):

There're two things:

1. In RxJS 6 you should use pipable operators. If you have to use the old "patch" style of operators you'll need to include `rxjs-compat` package
2. The `takeUntil()` operator takes as a parameter another Observable so what you have now will throw an error anyway.

   Maybe you should use `takeWhile()` instead. See this answer ([RxJS takeWhile but include the last value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641246/rxjs-takewhile-but-include-the-last-value/44644237#44644237)) if you want to also include the last value that completed the chain.