# Is there a 'smoother' way to code a progressbar?

Tags: angular, typescript

im trying to add a progressbar but sometimes it bugs out and fills too slow or too fast, most of the time it works fine though.

I also think that there must be a better way to programm this since mine does way to many calculations for a single progressbar i think.

Here is my Code:

ts:

```
startProgressbar(timeToWait: number) {
this.progress = 0;
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  let addvalue = (1 / timeToWait * 100) / 64;
  this.progress += addvalue;
  if (this.progress >= 100) {
    this.progress = 100;
    window.clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 15.625); }
```

The function gets called again as soon as its over since there will be the next slide of the slideshow directly after.

The progress value resembles the width of the progressbar, its always a percentage.

Where does the number 15.625 come from? 
Its simply a 64th of a second so the progressbar updates 64 times a second giving the illusion of moving smoothly.

My html is pretty basic:

```
<div class="progressbar" [ngStyle]="{'width': progress+'%'}"></div>
```

I hope you have a better approach than i did.
Thanks in advance

[EDIT]:
What i mean by it bugging out is that the progressbar sometimes starts filling late and therefor doesnt reach the end (100%) before the next slide appears and then the next ones timing is offset too.
Sometimes it starts early and then reaches the end (100%) too quickly so it stays at 100% for a while until the next slide appears.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "bugs out"?

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis Hope my edit helps you understand what i meant by bugging out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why not use Rxjs timer?

```
interval(timeToWait):Observable<number>
  {
    let progress = 0;
    return timer(0, timeToWait)
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(() => progress <= 100),
        map(()=>progress<100?progress:100),
        tap(() => (progress += 10))
      )
  }
```

Use

```
   this.interval(200).subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
```

**Update** add stackblitz: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rnjurb)

**Update 2** thanks to @Ritaj, timer return a stream (0,1,2,3,4,...), so we can use simple

```
 return timer(0, timeToWait)
  .pipe(
    map((progress)=>progress*5<100?progress*5:100),
    takeWhile((progress) => progress <= 100)
  )
```

**Update 3** thanks to [this answer of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641246/rxjs-takewhile-but-include-the-last-value), we  can included the last value whe we are using takeWhile, so, if is important the timeToWait we can replace the function interval by

```
 interval(timeToWait) {
    const initial = new Date().getTime();
    return timer(0, 200).pipe(
      map(()=> new Date().getTime()),
      takeWhile((res) => res<=initial+timeToWait,true),
      map(now=>{
        const porc = (100 * (now - initial)) / timeToWait;
        return porc<100?Math.round(porc):100
      })
    );
```

Comment: Because i've never used it, this was the first time i had to do with timing in angular, im only doing my apprenticeship since 5 months but i will make sure to look into that ^^

Comment: Also when i copy your example it doesn't work; Cant find name 'takeWhile', 'map', 'tap'.
I imported:
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import { timer } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/timer';

Comment: you must import from 'rxjs/operators, I updated the answer with a stackblitz: NOTE, from Angular 6 -I think remember-, Rxjs change to RXJS 6, so you import from 'rxjs' and 'rxjs/operators'

Comment: This is a better answer, but you should `map` before `takeWhile`. Also there is no neet to have a `progress` variable, just `map` and return the stream.

Comment: @niehoelzz, just updated the stackblitz and the answer with the comment of Ritaj

Comment: when i adjust the stepsize and the timeToWait, the progressbar doesn't reach 100% in time, why could that be? I changed progress to += 0.1 instead of 1 and timeToWait to * 0.1 aswell. On paper maths that would add up

Comment: I update the answer with another version of interval that use new Date

Answer (score 1):

I recommend following the Javascript [best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep) for waiting. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhsdan) is a stackblitz I've prepared with example code for a progress bar that uses the recommended practices.

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  public progress = 0;
  public timeToWait: number = 1;

  private default_ms = 8.33; // 120 times a second.
  private sleep(ms: number): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  public async startProgressBar(): Promise<void> {
    this.progress = 0;
    while(this.progress <= 100) {
      this.progress += (1 / this.timeToWait);
      await this.sleep(this.default_ms);
    }
  }
}
```

I can't say for sure why your solution "bugs out". Calling `window.clearInterval` inside the interval function seems like bad practice, but I can't be certain. Let me know if this solution works for you.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works perfectly for me ^^ Im not sure though why mine didn't :/ But using a promise to wait seems more appropiate Thank you for your help

Comment: why not use Rxjs?

Comment: No particular reason, RxJs could be used as well.

Comment: By the way, why does it work perfectly with 8.33 ms but not with 10?

Comment: Also when you type in 30 seconds it only takes 25 to reach the end, this effect magnifies when the progressbar has a greater time