# Angular Material Progress bar refresh YouTube emeded video

Tags: angular, youtube-api, progress-bar

I have simple progress bar based on [Angular Material Progress Bar](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview) made by [Eliseo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59662716/3381369) based on interval.

Issuse is that when progress bar is starded it refresh whole page instead of progress bar, even embeded YouTube video is refreshed.

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-progress-bar-decrease-6yhgdv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.module.ts) working example.

Any idea how to aproach to this issuse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

.TS

```
@Component({
...
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})

  public groundProgressbarValue: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(100);

this.groundProgressbarValue.next(100 - (sec * 100) / begin);
```

.HTML

```
<mat-progress-bar class="earth" mode="determinate" [value]="groundProgressbarValue | async"></mat-progress-bar>
```